# WPF Miller Columns

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I'm having a hard time implementing a [Miller Column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) interface in WPF, and was wondering if anyone has seen an implementation I could borrow from.  I've done some searching and can't find anything myself.

Currently I have my data organized in a hierarchy so that it can be placed in a TreeView, but I'd like to add the Miller Column view as an option in my program.

Comment: My suggestion is to explore the possibility to restyle the default template for the wpf treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **UPDATE**  I've enhanced my solution in a couple blog posts that can be found [here](https://codingforsmarties.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/wpf-miller-columns/) and [here](https://codingforsmarties.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/wpf-miller-columns-part-2/).  The new version allows for a more generic approach using MVVM.

A possible solution came to me, and Phil confirmed that it was the right approach.  I have to use an ItemsControl with a horizontal StackPanel as the ItemsPanel.  Then I created a DataTemplate for my data type and used it for the ItemTemplate on my ItemsControl.

The data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataNodeStackedDataTemplate" DataType="my:DataNode">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
             Style="{StaticResource StackedListBoxStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MillerColumnsView" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataNodeStackedDataTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The code-behind:

```
private void StackedListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                             SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (lb == null) return;
    var dn = lb.DataContext as DataNode;
    if (dn == null) return;
    int index = MillerColumnsView.Items.IndexOf(dn);
    if (index == -1) return;
    index++;
    while (MillerColumnsView.Items.Count > index)
        MillerColumnsView.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    if (dn.Children == null) return;
    // this Select() call performs some restructuring of the tree to 
    // appropriate display the correct nodes in the next ListBox
    dn.Select(dn.AvailableItems.ElementAt(lb.SelectedIndex));
    if (dn.Children.Count() == 0) return;
    MillerColumnsView.Items.Add(dn.Children.ElementAt(0));
}
```

This automatically removes and creates ListBoxes for each level of selection.  A little syling and it could look pretty, too!

Answer (score 1):

The UI for Miller Columns looks like multiple linked ListBox controls.

Here's an example: [WPF MVVM hierarchy selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827961/wpf-mvvm-hierarchy-selected-item/9830412#9830412)

Comment: That's only good if you have a static hierarchy.  What if you're looking at a file system (as can be viewed in a Mac Finder window)?  You need an indefinite number of `ListBox`es.

Comment: I you need a dynamic number of columns you could use an ItemsControl with a horizontal StackPanel at the ItemsPanel.  The ItemTemplate would contain a ListBox.  If you need splitters between each ListBox, then you need a Grid, but you'll have to manage the number of columns using code behind.

Comment: that's exactly the approach I'm taking.  I'm working on an example to post.